# How do I know at runtime which implementing classes are set for my Spring beans?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spring-bean

In hybris, is there an easy way to know which implementing class is being used for a certain Spring bean?

I mean, I can override a Bean by doing something like this:

```
<alias name="myCheckoutFacade" alias="checkoutFacade"/>
<bean id="myCheckoutFacade" class="com.pedra.facades.checkout.impl.MyCheckoutFacadeImpl" scope="tenant" parent="defaultCheckoutFacade">
    <property name="commerceCheckoutService" ref="myCommerceCheckoutService"/>
</bean>
```

... so now when Spring needs to create a bean with the alias `checkoutFacade` the implementing class will be `MyCheckoutFacadeImpl` as opposed to the overridden `defaultCheckoutFacade` which was defined in some other xml configuration file.

So is there a way to know at runtime which implementing class is being used for a certain Spring bean definition? Without having to debug the code, I mean.

Comment: Turn up the logging level.

Comment: org.springframework and stand back?

Comment: Another interesting thing you can do with Beanshell is selectively change the log levels at runtime. (Be careful on production - try this on dev machine first because it creates a very large log!) `org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG);` It would be better to set the level on a specific logger instead of just the root, but that's just a simple example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Beanshell or Groovy :-)

Checking the implementing class of a bean is just one of the many cool things you can do at runtime with Beanshell or Groovy.

*Disclaimer: Be careful running Beanshell or Groovy code on a production machine!*

- Log in to the HAC and go to **Console > Beanshell or Groovy**
- Execute the following code in either Beanshell or Groovy to get your implementing class:

  de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("checkoutFacade");

Both consoles will show the result of the last expression in the Result tab.

In the Groovy console for *Hybris 5.x*, simple execute the following:

```
checkoutFacade
```

As you can see, each bean is automatically `def`-ed into each Groovy script.

As for Beanshell, you could create a `bean` function in Beanshell:

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.Registry;
import de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.order.CheckoutFacade;

Object bean(String beanName) 
{
    return Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean(beanName);
}

CheckoutFacade checkoutFacade = (CheckoutFacade) bean("checkoutFacade");
print(checkoutFacade);
```

I ended up using Beanshell so much that I created my own wrapper application that allows me to develop Beanshell in Eclipse, and use Eclipse as the Beanshell console. But that's a whole other post!

**Resources:**

- [Beanshell User Manual](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html)
- [Beanshell Commands Documentation](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html) (Built-in functions like `print()`)